# Background Image doesnt show

Tags: html, css, image, tags, element

I have a div with a class called "wrapper'. When i try to add a background image to it in css it does not show, but the image shows up when i add it to the body.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Custom.css">

        <style>
            .wrapper{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-image: url(login-register.jpg);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the structure of your files? where is this file in comparison to the image?

Comment: My guess is that your url in your css isn't pointing to the correct location, for example you may need something like the following: ../../../project/assets/images/x.jpg

Comment: Is "login-register.jpg" in the same folder as this HTML file?

Comment: No.My url is working fine when i add my background-image to the body so the issue is not the url.Its something else

Comment: @Stuart.. Yes sir it is.

Comment: As soon as i replace the class wrapper with body the background image appears :)

Comment: Have you given the `body` 100% width/height too..? You should.

Comment: My instructor in the course did the exact same thing and he's image is displaying so?

Answer (score 1):

In given example .wrapper after rendering has 0px height so background image is just not visible. 
Height in percentage is relative to its parent - so if parent has 0 height child will have 0 height too (as long as there are no elements with height inside child).

You can add `min-height: 100vh` or `min-height: 300px` to make it work.

Comment: My Instructor on the course did the exact same thing and the image is displaying so its a bit strange that one thing dont work for the other one

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :)

```
.wrapper{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
     background-image: url(login-register.jpg);
}
```